# Export the imported XML sheet into excel using vba

Tags: xml, excel

I am new to vba and I am trying to work on a XML file by importing it into excel,make some changes and export the changed excel sheet to the same xml file again.I was successful in importing the xml in my excel and edit it but not getting how to save the changed sheet again to xml.

I have the path of the xml file in "Path" which I use to import the xml file now i want to export the changed excel sheet to "Path".

A sample VBA code will be a great help.

Comment: Can you show what the xml file looks like, how you import it in Excel and what specific problem you have saving it to "Path".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled the developer ribbon in Excel. Select "Source" from the XML section. You should be able to see the map and name associated with the XML in a new frame on the right of the worksheet.

If you want to export either save as XML or simply ...

```
Sub saveAsXml()
ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("my_map").Export URL:="path ..."
End Sub
```

Hope that helps